# Saving styles to database

Tags: postgis, style, database, qgis-2.14

In QGIS, the option to save the style to a database (postgres) does not appear in the drop down list if the postgis table has been opened using add vector layer and then entering the postgres database details, rather than add postgis layer

I see that the connection string is different (PG:dbname) but why does this make a difference?

I am using 2.14

Comment: Hello, excuse my question.
You managed to record in different postgres styles, for several layers, and then be able to import them.
In my project, I have many layers each with its specific style. Said project is executed in different cases and I require to be able to load the styles every time.
How did you do it?
Best regards

Comment: Please put an appropriate question title.